# Plot a chart directly from a function in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I need an help with chart plotting in Excel (I'm using Excel 2016) let's say we have a simple function like:

```
y=1/x
```

Right now, to plot a chart based on this function I use two columns. In the left column I insert the value for X variable with a setted interval, and on the right column I insert the function using the value from the left cells. Like this:

```
A          B

X          Y
1         =1/A1
1,5       =1/A2
2         =1/A3
2,5       =1/A4
```

And then plot a chart using the data in column B. I want to know if there is a way to plot the chart using only the function, without inserting the data manually like in the example. Something like defining the range of the variables and then automatically plot the chart. In the past versions if I remember well, there was the "chart wizard" but then was removed.

Thank you

Comment: This would make an interesting little add-in.

Comment: Jan Karel Pieterse shows how to do this in [Charting A Mathematical Equation Using Excel And Defined Names](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/ChartAnEquation00.asp). It's a cute little academic exercise, but for the most part, it's better to put X and Y values in the worksheet and chart those. (And the old chart wizard did not allow this either.)